# A coin toss problem which to make n coins be heads

Tags: probability, inequality

There are n unbiased coins, and perform the following process to generate all heads. Toss all n
coins independently at random onto a table. Each round consists of picking up all the tails-up coins and tossing them onto the table again. Repeat until all coins are heads.
(a) What is the expected number of rounds performed by the process? Give an asymptotic upper bound
as tight as possible.
(b) What is the expected number of coin tosses performed by the process? Give an asymptotic upper
bound as tight as possible.

Facing this problem, I have make some tryout as to answer problem . I try to perform a mathematic expectation of the rounds (1,2,3...) and in each part it is a Bernoulli distribution(for example when round is 2, which means the first round a1 coins are heads and the second round a2 coins are heads as a1+a2=n),but this can't give me a upper bound or to say I have no idea how to do it, then came here ask for help.

Comment: Well, there's a clear recursion.  That may or may not be the best way to get a full solution, but it certainly lets you compute a lot of values quickly which should at least give you a better sense of the problem.  Note that the number of tosses it takes is simply the maximum of the number of tosses it takes for each coin separately.

Comment: @lulu,wow thanks! This is a good hint as I can treat every coin as a geometric distribution, is that correct? Let me go and try for it~

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I do recommend implementing the recursion, though.  Whatever result you end up with, you'll want to check it against a reasonably long list of examples and the recursion is the best way to get values.

Comment: @lulu thanks for it , let me go ahead to do it!

Comment: Hint: The b) question has an easy exact solution for each n, no need for asymptotics.

Comment: @Ingix thanks I got the answer that this is actually 2n.

Comment: For part (a), I get $2, \frac{8}{3}, \frac{22}{7}, \frac{368}{105}, \ldots$

Comment: The first paragraph appears to be copied from another source (e.g., The Algorithm Design Manual, Steven S. Skiena, p.193), without attribution.  Copying without attribution constitutes plagiarism, which is not cool.  We require you credit the original source of all copied material: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing